# Simulate a POST webhook in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, http-post, webhooks

What's the way to simulate a webhook, just to test things on Jenkins?

I run

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST --data 'payload={}' 'http://172.28.22.60:8080/github-webhook/'
```

And on Jenkins log I get in the end

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not intended to be browsed interactively (must specify payload parameter)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubWebHook.doIndex(GitHubWebHook.java:168)
    ... 53 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this code from [Subversion post-commit hook](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) help?

```
HEADER="Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
CRUMB=`$WGET --auth-no-challenge --output-document - ${CISERVER}/${CRUMB_ISSUER_URL}`
if [ "$CRUMB" != "" ]; then HEADER=$CRUMB; fi

$WGET \
    --auth-no-challenge \
    --header $HEADER \
    --post-data "`$SVNLOOK changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
    --output-document "-"\
    --timeout=2 \
    ${CISERVER}/${NOTIFY_URL}
```